# How do I use Sinon with Typescript?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, sinon

If I use sinon with typescript then how do I cast the sinon mock to an instance of my object?

For instance a SinonMock would be returned but my controller under test may require a specific service passed in to its constructor.

```
var myServiceMock: MyStuff.MyService = <MyStuff.MyService (sinon.mock(MyStuff.MyService));

controllerUnderTest = new MyStuff.MyController(myServiceMock, $log);
```

Can sinon be used with Typescript?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may need to use an `<any>` type assertion to make the type wide before you narrow it to your specific type:

```
var myServiceMock: MyStuff.MyService = 
    <MyStuff.MyService> <any> (sinon.mock(MyStuff.MyService));
```

Just to clarify one behaviour of sinon - although you pass in `MyStuff.MyService`, whatever you pass to the `mock` method is only used to provide better error messages.

If you want the mock to have methods and properties, [you need to add them](http://sinonjs.org/docs/).

If you want automatically created fakes, you can grab the `FakeFactory` from [tsUnit](https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/tsUnit/blob/master/tsUnit/Scripts/tsUnit/tsUnit.ts), which creates a fake version with some default values that you can opt to override - in JavaScript this is pretty easy stuff (plus by not using too much mock functionality, you can ensure you are testing behaviour rather than implementation).

Example use of `FakeFactory`:

```
var target = tsUnit.FakeFactory.getFake<RealClass>(RealClass);
var result = target.run();
this.areIdentical(undefined, result);
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something similar to this.  I also learned I was using the sinon object incorrectly, I didn't realize all I needed to do is use the original MyService instance in calls and it uses the sinon mocks/stubs.  What you have put here seems correct for what I was asking in any case, thanks!

Comment: I was back to this and it seems like it doesn't work.  myServiceMock doesn't appear like it has any methods.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you given it an expectation? `myServiceMock.expects("doSomething").returns(42);`

Comment: I tried, but the issue seem to be that sinon can only mock and instance of the object and not the type based on the constructor.  I guess that makes sense really, since mocking a javascript type would be difficult.  But, that leaves me still have to construct an instance of this class ( with mocks passed into the ctor ), and then mocking the instance.  I can't think of anything to do, but just create the mocks by hand.

Answer (score 32):

Sinon can create a stub based on a constructor quite easily if, instead of `mock`, you use the `createStubInstance` method.

An example using [mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha), [chai](http://chaijs.com/), [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) and [sinon-chai](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai), could look like this:

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as chai from 'chai';

// ... imports for the classes under test

const expect    = chai.expect;
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");

chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('MyController', () => {
    it('uses MyService', () => {

        let myService  = sinon.createStubInstance(MyStuff.MyService),
            controller = new MyStuff.MyController(myService as any, ...);

        // ... perform an action on the controller 
        // that calls myService.aMethodWeAreInterestedIn

        // verify if the method you're interested in has been called if you want to
        expect(myService.aMethodWeAreInterestedIn).to.have.been.called;
    });
});
```

I've [published an article](https://janmolak.com/mocking-javascript-a-little-26efb5f7f52a#.ulfyw64hq), which you might find useful if you'd like to learn more about the different test doubles and how to use them with Sinon.js.

Hope this helps!

Jan

Comment: You can also use `import * as sinonChai from 'sinon-chai';` assuming you have the types installed: `npm i --save-dev @types/sinon-chai`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an error "Type 'SinonStubbedInstance<Foo>' is not assignable to type type 'Foo'. Property 'bar' is missing in type 'SinonStubbedInstance<Foo>'." because `createStubInstance` returns a `SinonStubbedInstance<Foo>` but what I need to pass to my test function is not a `SinonStubbedInstance<Foo>` but an actual `Foo`.

Comment: This also doesn't seem to work for types with explicit constructors that take arguments. I get `TypeError: The constructor should be a function.`. The article unfortunately also takes this "happy path" approach as though classes with multi-arg constructors simply didn't exist!

Comment: @Frans - When passing a stubbed instance to a consumer use `stubbedFoo as unknown as Foo` - see for example https://github.com/serenity-js/serenity-js/blob/master/packages/core/spec/stage/Stage.spec.ts#L58

Comment: Thanks @JanMolak. Turned out my `The constructor should be a function` error had a different cause from what I had assumed: I was importing the constructor but it was pulling through as `undefined` for some reason, and obviously `undefined` is not a function.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you got to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 7):

Use [ts-sinon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-sinon).

It lets you:

- stub objects
- stub interfaces

Comment: this is a great answer!

Answer (score 5):

In Typescript this can be achieved by using sinon.createStubInstance and SinonStubbedInstance class.

Example:

```
let documentRepository: SinonStubbedInstance<DocumentRepository>;

documentRepository = sinon.createStubInstance(DocumentRepository);
```

Now you have a full intellisense for working with all stubbed methods of this class.

Example Arrange:

```
documentRepository.delete.resolves({deletedCount: 1});

documentRepository.update.throws(error);
```

Example Assert:

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(documentRepository.update);
```

There is only one place where you would need to perform type casting and that is the initiallization of the class you want to unit test.

Example:

```
documentsController =
  new DocumentsController(
    userContext,
    documentRepository as unknown as DocumentRepository);
```

Hope this will help.
More on this [article](https://medium.com/@milos.d.josic/mocking-with-sinon-in-typescript-7e6598a3975f).

Comment: I get a tslint error "Cannot find name 'unknown'.".

Comment: `unknown` was introduced in TypeScript 3. Using a newer typescript compiler fixed this for me (in IntelliJ: **Settings** > **Languages & Frameworks** > **Typescript**.